# Can I add an entry to mysql and return a column if it's not present in one query?

Tags: sql, mysql, select

Can I have one query to check if an entry is in a mysql table, and if it is present, return a column, but if it's not present, insert it and return a value?  I have a users table with the following layout:

```
userID - int, auto-increment
userName - varchar(100)
active - tinyint(1)
```

I want to do something like

```
select userID from users where userName='<some value>'
```

and if the userName exists, then return the userID, if not, insert it and return the newly incremented userID.

I know I can do this in two queries (one to check if userName exists, then another one to insert), but can I do it in one?  I could create a stored procedure to only have one thing to call from my code, but the only way I can envision that stored procedure is to also do the two queries.

I see things like REPLACE INTO and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, but these only seem to work on updates, not on selecting a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if it exists and insert it in one query:

```
insert into users (userName) values ('<some value>')
where not exists (
    select * from users where userName = '<some value>'
)
```

But after that you'll still need to select the userid:

```
select userid from users where userName = '<some value>'
```

I don't think an INSERT can be inside a SELECT.

Comment: actually if userid is the PK on the table, you can get it back all at once using mysql_insert_id()

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to create a stored procedure that will do this for you, though many people I know would argue against this type of logic existing on the database.

Comment: But wouldn't the stored procedure still have to do two transactions?